# Djoser with DRF Error username field is required

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, djoser

I am using djoser with django rest framework, and I want to remove the username field from the create user form:

**`settings.py`:**

```
'SERIALIZERS': {
    'user_create': 'user.serializers.UserRegistrationSerializer',
},
```

**`serializers.py`:**

```
class UserRegistrationSerializer(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ('email', 'password')
```

I received the following error. How do you fix this?

> ```
> TypeError at /auth/users/create
> create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
> ```

Comment: Salaam @Hassam Ali did you figure this out? I am trying solve the same issue atm.

Answer (score 0):

According to djoser documentation [User Create](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/base_endpoints.html#user-create)

> Use this endpoint to register new user. Your user model manager should
>   implement [create_user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) method and have [`USERNAME_FIELD`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.USERNAME_FIELD) and
>   [`REQUIRED_FIELDS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser.REQUIRED_FIELDS) fields

You have to customize your user model not the serializers.

I'm fact I don't recognize the serializers you used as belonging to djoser.

Additional questions:

- Do you want to replace `username` filed with `email`?